# Biztalk Rule Engine

Tags: biztalk-rule-engine

I want to try the rule engine of biztalk, but without installing the biztalk server, I found this tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33143/Developing-with-the-Microsoft-Business-Rule-Engine which indicates how to only install the rule engine.

When I run the Business Rule Composer, I have to indicate an sql server and a database name, why do I have to do that? I mean do I have to install sql server to use the Biztalk BRE? I will not get data from database and i don't want to install sql server, is it possible?

Also can I create rules without the Business Rule Composer?

Thanks.

Comment: BTS and BRC support the import of [BPEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Execution_Language) so you could look into creating your Business Rules that way (never tried this myself) but overall you'll not find much support for developing BTS artifacts without BTS tools.

Comment: [Biztalk - possible to create rule/policy programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3908582/205233) might be worth a look too.

Comment: thanks but I don't want to use BRC at all, I want to be able to create rules without using a graphic tool.

Comment: The answer in the linked post suggests that there's a schema definition for composing a Xml doc for BTS Rules. This would make you independent from BRC creating rules just by writing Xml.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it and post feedback.

Comment: i have installed biztalk, but i couldn't find the Samples folder. could anyone please tell me what i have to do ?

Comment: IIRC, the BizTalk SDK is separate installation package. Check around [Samples in the SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560186.aspx) on MSDN.